# Multiple calculations on the same set of data: ruby or database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance

I have a model `Transaction` for which I need to display the results of many calculations on many fields for a subset of `transactions`.

I've seen 2 ways to do it, but am not sure which is the best. I'm after the one that will have the least impact in terms of performance when data set grows and number of concurrent users increases.

```
data[:total_before] = Transaction.where(xxx).sum(:amount_before)
data[:total_after] = Transaction.where(xxx).sum(:amount_after)
...
```

or

```
transactions = Transaction.where(xxx)
data[:total_before]= transactions.inject(0) {|s, e| s + e.amount_before }
data[:total_after]= transactions.inject(0) {|s, e| s + e.amount_after }
...
```

edit: the where clause is always the same.

Which one should I choose? (or is there a 3rd, better way?)

Thanks, P.

Comment: Side note: array.inject(0) {|s, e| s + e.amount_before } -> array.sum(&:amount_before). But that's for normal enumerables, for AR is sum(:amount_before) as Nikita says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not to nag, but what about

```
transactions = Transaction.where(xxx)
data[:total_before] = transactions.sum(:amount_before)
data[:total_after] = transactions.sum(:amount_before)
```

? This looks like the union of strengths of methods 1 and 2 :) You reuse search results and employ more clean rails-specific `sum` aggregator.

PS If you were asking whether it's possible to rely on Rails in caching results of `Transaction.where(xxx)` query, that I don't know. And when I don't know, I prefer to play safe.

Comment: Just so you know, yes you can rely on rails query caching. It is a part of well-document public API. However, you should not do so as to not repeat yourself twice.

Answer (score 4):

Really you're talking about scalability.

If you're talking about millions of rows and needing to do calculations on them, then which do you think would be faster?

1. Asking the DBM to summarize millions of rows and return you two numbers.
2. Returning millions of query results across the network which you iterate over twice.

In the first scenario you can scale up your DB host with faster CPUs, more RAM, faster drives or pre-compute your values at regular intervals. The calculations you want done in the DBM are exactly the sort of things it's written to do.

In the second scenario you have to scale up your computing host, and maybe the switch connecting the DBM and computing host, plus maybe the database host because it will have to retrieve and push the data. Imagine the impact on the network as it's handling the data, and the impact on the computing host's CPU as it's doing everything.

I'd do the first one as it seems a lot more scalable to me.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the first example. It doesn't delegate any processing to database, it's just a shorthand for `inject` version: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum  Rails isn't so smart as you think :)

Comment: Or may be I misunderstand `where`?

Comment: The first example will require at least one database hit. If the undefined `where` clause is identical, which we don't know, then the `sum` could be written to grab the summed value for several columns. Either way, it is a lot more efficient than asking the database to return all matching records and processing it in the calling code, which is why I said it's a scalability issue, and determining that pretty much answers the OPs question.

Comment: the where clause is indeed always the same (I've edited the question). And I'm not talking millions of rows either... merely a few tens of thousands.